# Mocking ormlite database

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, ormlite, android-testing

I have an `OrmLiteBaseActivity` and in the `onCreate()` of this activity i read some data from a database. Depending on the data read I change the visibility of some views.

I'm writing tests for this activity. How can I mock the database (or even use another test database) so I can change the data in the database according to my tests needs so I can test different cases depending on that data. I want to test the visibility of the views depending on the data read.

Any ideas, guides, examples or anything else that will help me is welcomed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm writing tests for this activity. How can I mock the database (or even use another test database) so I can change the data in the database according to my tests needs so I can test different cases depending on that data.

All of the database stuff is driven internally to ORMLite with 4 interfaces:

- [`ConnectionSource`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/support/ConnectionSource.html) which gives connections to the database
- [`DatabaseConnection`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/support/DatabaseConnection.html) which represents the connection
- [`CompiledStatement`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/support/CompiledStatement.html) which represents a compiled SQL statement
- [`DatabaseResults`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/support/DatabaseResults.html) which gives returns from `CompiledStatement.runQuery()`

When you construct your DAOs, you pass in a `ConnectionSource` implementation that gives `DatabaseConnection`s, etc..  You can certain use EasyMock or some little concrete class to mock out these 4 interfaces.  It's a little complex to do so but it can be done.

The unit tests for ORMLite are pretty extensive.  For some partial examples you can take a look at:

- [`FieldTypeTest.testForeignAutoRefresh()`](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/blob/master/src/test/java/com/j256/ormlite/field/FieldTypeTest.java#L562) -- it shows the mocking of the `ConnectionSource` and `DatabaseConnection` but doesn't go all of the way to `DatabaseResults`.
- [`TableUtilsTest.testStatement()`](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/blob/master/src/test/java/com/j256/ormlite/table/TableUtilsTest.java#L472) -- it shows some complex mocking of `DatabaseConnection`, `CompiledStatement`, and `DatabaseResults`.
- [`H2CompiledStatement` and other classes](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/tree/master/src/test/java/com/j256/ormlite/h2) in that test package.  This is the test code that ORMLite uses to test the various database operations.  H2++.